# How to disable the spinner when using search function in datatables in a Rails application

Tags: jquery, spinner, datatables

I have just put in a spinner in my Rails application that uses jQuery datatables plugin.  The code is really simple:

I have a div with and id of spinner like so:

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner">
    <img id="img-spinner" src="/assets/spinner.gif" alt="Loading"/>
</div>
```

Plus a bit of jQuery code to hook on to the spinner id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
      $(this).show();
    }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
      $(this).hide();
    }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
   });
</script>
```

This works great.  Except that I do not want to display the spinner image when the user types in a search string in the datatables search box.  Since datatables uses Ajax to a) populate the table during initial load and b) also when sending in the search string as the user types every character.  There is simply too much flickering of the spinner image.  I do not have too much experience with datatables yet, so there might be a callback that can be used for this purpose?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Bharat

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and the best solution is to disable the global ajax for a specific path. You can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "test.html",
   global: false,
   // ...
 });
```

Read more about global events [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events). With the above code, `global` is `false` when requesting test.html. I assume you can use the same thing only for your search functionality.

Comment: Hello Amir,  Thanks for your response.  But this doesn't quite work.  Please allow me to elaborate:  I have a "/states.json" url where the datatable retrieves its contents from.  As I type in the search string in the search box, it fires off ajax request to the same URL with request parameters.  I specified the URL as url: "/states.json" which does not prevent the spinner from showing up as I type additional search characters.

Comment: I tried this again and it worked. You have to use ajax and not `.load`, `.get` or `.post`. Only `.ajax` supports the global flag.